# Simulink integrate for a set duration of time

Tags: time, simulink

Could I ask how one might integrate a signal for a set duration of time in Simulink?

I am running a simulation for 60s. Prior to this I manually monitoring the current flow through the capacitor until it is "charged",  which was about 5s. After which I only want to integrate that signal for 0 - 5secs only. This could be done by setting manually a time duration to integrate or by monitoring in the model when current flow peak has plateaued. Former should be easier for my purposes.

Thus far I have tried the Continuous-time integration of the input signal but it does not have a time duration parameter.

[Simulink integrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVN41.jpg)

I wonder if a switch or step block or custom function block may work.

Comment: You'll want to use the "External Reset" parameter in the integrator block. Select "Level Hold" and provide the reset input (the second input to the integrator block) with a boolean signal representing when you want to reset (i.e., don't want to integrate). This boolean signal should be true at all times except the duration during which you want to integrate.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really pointed me in the right direction. I did what you said using the integrator block with a external reset and level hold. Then used a boolean operator to tell it to integrate for 5s. Was then stuck on the trying to keep the accumulated previous integrated value after 5s rather than it resetting to zero. This was fixed by setting initial condition source to external and setting a feedback loop from the previous value.  [Diagram Simulink with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBBc.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Patrick for the solution.
This is what the answer looks like with a cleaner boolean operator

Diagram
[image: Diagram]
Output
[image: Output]